# How can I get all results that are a certain date away from my value?

Tags: mysql, datetime

Using php i want to make the following mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE AUTODATE > (24HRS DIFFERENCE FROM CURRENT DATE)
```

the `AUTODATE var CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` has values in format  Y-m-d H:i:s

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You might want

```
SELECT ... WHERE yourDateField > Curdate() - Interval 1 day
```

or maybe

```
SELECT ... WHERE yourDateField > Now() - Interval 24 hour
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= autodate;
```

read the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).